# Banno Plugin Servers hosted on localhost, with redirect URIs that are not localhost based

Tags: reverse-proxy, http-proxy-middleware, banno-digital-toolkit

The Banno plugin servers are hosted on localhost on different ports (e.g. http://localhost:21770 and http://localhost:21771), however, the corresponding external App redirect URIs are not localhost-based (e.g. https://somedomain.com/org1/cb1 and https://somedomain.com/org2/cb1). The plugin servers formulate the required Redirect URI for authentication.

Now, when I use the localhost URL http://localhost:21770/cb1 in the browser it pops up a credentials dialog but even after entering the correct credentials, it gets locked up on that UI.  I'm seeking advice on whether this setup is right and expected to work and any potential improvements. Are there any concerns or better practices I should be aware of?

Background (just for the context): I'm working on a dynamic reverse proxy setup using Express.js and the http-proxy-middleware package in Node.js. The goal is to dynamically route incoming requests to different backend Banno plugin servers based on configuration files. The reverse proxy server shall receive the Redirect URI from a client App and then it shall forward it to the banno plugin server hosted on localhost which in turn does the authentication, generates the response and gives it back to the reverse proxy server.

Comment: Apologies, but I'm getting a bit lost on the sequence of URLs and where they're getting called to/from. Do you have a sketch or diagram you can add to your question which will help us understand the network and machines involved? There may be something subtle we're not quite getting from the problem text description alone.

Comment: I have rephrased the question for more clarity. Please check now.

Comment: It sounds like the mixing and matching of localhost and non-localhost URLs might be causing same-origin issues with the browser itself? https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/authentication/